# ComponentQuery selector for child elements only

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a set of Controller/View that are composed dynamically, each one have a "selector" list and a "container", such container can have another selector+container pair, and so on. Which are instances of the same root selector+container Controller.

This is the heading definition of the Controller  (the abstract class):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.explorer.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    refs: [
        {ref: 'explorerContainer', selector: '[itemId="explorerContainer]'},
        {ref: 'explorerSelector', selector: '[itemId="explorerSelector]'}
    ],
```

The thing is I don't know what should be the ComponentQuery selector to match only the child elements of my controller with such itemId. Because by using [itemId="explorerContainer"] to match the component it does so globally, answering the top-most container in the composition tree.

In previous experiments I did with ExtJS 3 I accessed child elements by means of myComponent.getComponent('...'), but now there's no getComponent() and I could'n find an equivalent in ExtJS 4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing a bit controllers with views in your question. For example "child elements of my controller".  The controller is not a component - just an observer of events. Views have children components, etc.

You need to get a little bit more familiar with `Ext.ComponentQuery` class. You can experiment with it in Firebug on your app or demo pages. You just pop open firebug console and type `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel')`  - then replace panel with whatever you think is the right expression and test it out. If you install Illuminations For Developers plugin - you will get Ext components back instead of generic JS objects - this is tremendously helpful.

Docs have some examples of queries: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery . You'll find the "`>`" symbol restricts query to immediate children.

Hope this helps. If not post some more of your code and we can help you create some selectors.

Comment: Yes, I mixed controllers and views, I have an MVC (MVP actually) past and there controllers and views always come together. 

I understand the ">" operator in the ComponentQuery selector syntax, but that doesn't work because it is global, and I don't know beforehand how deep the children is (think of a dynamically generated GUI).

In my view composition I can have Selectors (S) and Containers (C), composed like this:
    ViewPort(S,C(S,C(S,C(S,C(...))))).

Comment: if you don't know the depth then you just use "viewport mycontainer[property=value]"

Comment: But what if I don't know which property is different? I don't want to tag every instance, this Selector+Container pair should only know about itself and be able to be embedded (child of) anything else, and as deep as needed. It is a common MVC/MVP pattern I've been working with in Smalltalk since the beginning of time, it's just I don't know how to do the same in ExtJS4, but my answer below was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do component.query('selector') to query the subtree starting at your component.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Ext.ComponentQuery documentation I found this at the bottom of it:

> "For easy access to queries based from a particular Container see the
>   Ext.container.Container.query, Ext.container.Container.down and
>   Ext.container.Container.child methods. Also see Ext.Component.up."

So **Ext.container.ContainerView** (xtype: *container*) implements **child(*[selector]*)**, which answer the first child element matching the selector string argument.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-child

It does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: sure, the up and down methods are handy.